# How do I isolate the number after the decimal point for error checking in Visual Basics

Tags: vb.net

I am making a program with text boxes that have input numbers of (.5). If the user inputs 0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5 etc, its alright. But if he/she should enter 2.4, 3.6, etc. I have to produce an error message. What should I put in my If statement in relation to the number after the decimal point. I would really appreciate the help. Thanks!

Comment: use a numericupdown to avoid the issue entirely (1 decimal, increment .5)

Comment: @Plutonix to the best of my knowledge a NumericUpDown will not prevent the user from writing whatever numeric value he wants?

Comment: ....and Readonly = True (spinners work, no keyboard entry, sorry)

Comment: @Plutonix I think the end user will be annoyed past 3, but for small values that could do, yeah.

Comment: @Crono1981 it also responds to mousewheel which can spin thru a range pretty quickly.

Comment: Yeah but honestly what would you think of an app that won't let you type in 585.5 but allow to spin up to it? That's solving a problem by introducing yet another problem IMHO. Don't take the keyboard away from the user, he will hate you for that. :p

Answer (score 2):

Use the `Mod` operator. If any modulo of the value is different from zero then the value can't be right.

```
If value Mod 0.5 <> 0 Then
    'Value is wrong
End If
```

The Mod operator divides `value` by `0.5`, and returns the remainder from the division.  So if the remainder is zero, then `value` is divisible by 0.5.